# Manually hashing password the same as ASP.NET Identity v2.2.1

Tags: asp.net-identity-2, password-hash

I have an ASP.NET Web Api that makes use of ASP.NET Identity v2.2.1 to manage users. I am able to add/edit users without issue. However, I have a second project that cannot make use of the API but needs to be able to change a `Users` password directly via the database.

I am trying to figure out how to hash the password entered by the user without going through the API. I need to make sure that I am using the same hashing algorithm that ASP.NET Identity is using. I came across some code in [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227829/password-hash-doesnt-match-when-re-using-existing-microsoft-identity-user-tab) but I am not sure if it is the same hashing algorithm used by v2.2.1.

```
using using System.Security.Cryptography;

public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    private const int PBKDF2IterCount = 1000; // default for Rfc2898DeriveBytes
    private const int PBKDF2SubkeyLength = 256 / 8; // 256 bits
    private const int SaltSize = 128 / 8; // 128 bits

    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }

    // Produce a version 0 (see comment above) text hash.
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] subkey;
    using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, PBKDF2IterCount))
    {
        salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
        subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
    }

    var outputBytes = new byte[1 + SaltSize + PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, SaltSize);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + SaltSize, PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
}
```

I would like to avoid having to add ASP.NET Identity as a dependency to this project hence why I would like to `hash` the password manually.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `SimpleCrypto`

This is how I've used that in a project I believe this will help you. One can add this `DLL` from `nuget`

```
         [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
     {
         try
         {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 {
                     var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
                     var encrypPass = crypto.Compute(model.Password);
                     var newUser = db.Users.Create();
                     newUser.Email = model.Email;
                     newUser.Password = encrypPass;
                     newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
                    // newUser.Name = model.UserName;
                     newUser.Username = model.UserName;
                     //newUser.AddedBy = model.;
                     db.Users.Add(newUser);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
             }
         }
         catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
         {
             foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                     eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                 foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                         ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                 }
             }
             throw;
         }

         return View();
     }
```

Your valid check at login will be like this

```
        private bool IsValid(string email, string password)
    {
        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
        bool isValid = false;

        {
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
            if (user != null)
            {
               if (user.Password == crypto.Compute(password, user.PasswordSalt))
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: Only Identity stores password hash and salt in the same field in the DB. So you'll need to account for that. And this question is month old - I think the OP already found the solution.